# How to activate the reduce method with input value,

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

How to activate the reduce method with input value
can anyone help with the modification or the idea

```
let catchvalue = document.querySelector("input");
let btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener(`click`, function(){
  let emptyarray = [10, 10];
  let totalvalue = emptyarray.unshift(catchvalue.value);
  let averagenumbers = emptyarray.reduce(function(acc, curr){
    return acc + curr;
    let extract = parseInt(emptyarray);
  });
});
```

Comment: <form>
  <input type="text" name="Amount" class="Amount">
  <button type="button" name="submit" >Calculate</button>
</form>

Comment: Please click [edit], then the button shaped like `[<>]`  and produce a [mcve] with actual HTML and input and expected output instead of just duplicating whatever you write

Comment: And please look at [Stackoverflow markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: no idea what you want to do and why you pasted your code twice lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- NEVER call anything name or ID=submit in a form you want to process with JavaScript –
- Nothing will execute after a return statement –
- What do expect parseInt(emptyarray); would do? Did you want perhaps to do this? emptyarray.unshift(+catchvalue.value); –

Here is my guess what you wanted

```js
let catchvalue = document.getElementById("Amount");
let btn = document.getElementById("calc");
let emptyarray = [10, 10];
btn.addEventListener(`click`, function() {
  let totalvalue = emptyarray.unshift(+catchvalue.value);
  let total = emptyarray.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
  let avg = (total / emptyarray.length).toFixed(2);
  console.log("Average of", emptyarray, "'s total of", total, "is", avg)
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Amount" class="Amount">
<button type="button" id="calc">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Exactly, thank you so much, Mplungjan.